# Mail Notification using Selenium

Tags: selenium, email

I have a doubt like ... Can we use mails in automation(selenium).For ex, I am submitting a form , can we use selenium
- to send email
- to verify whether email has been received by that recepient and can we process that through selenium

I have read like we should not automate with gmail as per aggreement.I am not sure about this .

Comment: I don't know what Gmail's policy is, but it sounds like you just want to verify that a mail has been received and that you won't be using Selenium to spam anyone. I don't see why their conditions would prohibit you from doing that.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. You can use Java Mail API to achieve this.

Otherwise use public email systems like [Mailinator](https://www.mailinator.com/). By using the API, we can fetch email content. Please read API docs for more info.

Similar [question](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2431/is-mail-testing-with-selenium-possible) asked before.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!. You should highlight the most important information from your link in your answer. The link can go down in few years, and you answer will not be very helpful.